# comparaciones de listas

Tags: python, diccionarios, comparaciones

tengo el siguiente código que me compara la lista de las claves del diccionario con una lista que se genera por teclado. El código funciona, mi pregunta es como puedo generar la comparación en el orden del input y no en el de la posición de la lista de las claves del diccionario. Muchas gracias ante cualquier ayuda

**Entrada** --->b a c g d
**salida**----->a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

Lo que necesito es algo así

**Entrada** --->b a c g d
**salida**----->b', 'a', 'c', 'd'

```
string1=input()
string11=string1.split(' ')
lista2=[]

productos=(list(data.keys()))
for i in productos: 
  if i in string11:
    lista2.append(i)

print(string11)

print(lista2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'a': 0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
#linea = input()
linea = "b a c g d\n"
lista2 = [letra for letra in linea.strip().split() if letra in data]
print(lista2)
```

produce:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

#### Análisis

Tomamos la línea ingresada por teclado, algo como

```
linea = "b a c g d\n"
```

y aplicamos `strip` para eliminar los espacios de más antes y después de la letra, con lo que queda asi:

```
linea = "b a c g d"
```

Le aplicamos `split` para convertirlo en una lista de valores, resultando en:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'd']
```

Eso es lo que produce la expresión `linea.strip().split()`.

Finalmente, hacemos una comprensión de listas con el adicional de chequear primero si la letra cumple la condición, usando:

```
if letra in data
```

que resulta `True` si `letra` es una llave de `data`.

El resultado una lista con las letras en la secuencia de entrada.

Teniendo la lista, puedes formatearla para cubrir cualquier necesidad. Por ejemplo:

```
print(*lista2) => b a c d
print(''.join(lista2)) => bacd
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice una modificación en el for:

```
data = {'a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d'}
string1=input()
string11=string1.split(' ')
lista2=[]

productos=(list(data.keys()))
for i in string11: 
  if i in productos:
    lista2.append(i)

print(string11)
print(lista2)
```

Muy bien, como vemos en el for lo que me va a iterar en i son los elementos de mi lista ingresada por teclado `for i in string11:`, adentro vamos a verificar si esos elementos están en la lista de claves `if i in productos:` , si es asi agregamos ese elemento en la lista lista2, y asi se estaria agregando en orden como has digitado por teclado..
salida:

```
b a c g d
['b', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'd']
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```